# Question on existence and atomicity of a geometric morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, topos-theory

I am curious to know where we can find a geometric morphism from the Zariski topos to the étale topos and more specifically when this is atomic. I would like to know, actually, in which instances is the Zariski topos atomic over the étale topos. Where can I read about that?

Thanks

Comment: This is not exactly my research area but I thought this question would be quite natural. Is it not known when the Zariski topos is atomic over the étale topos? Has this question not been asked? If this is true, I am struck; can someone shed some light? I do not know how to interpret the lack of reply. Thanks.